# How to run a Webapplication using Spring+EclipseLink jpa on Jboss v6

Tags: java, spring, jboss, eclipselink, jboss6.x

I am trying to learn Spring JPA with EclipseLink. I have running standalone Spring webApplication that just shows a few JSP pages.

In another eclipse project I have a working simple example of eclipseLink JPA. 
But when I tried to integrate the Spring WebApp with the eclipselink code , it fails to start because jboss tries to load the hibernate instead of eclipseLink.

Below is the error - I guess, I am missing some basic steps for deploying a simple WebApp using Spring+EclipseLink on Jboss 6. This is purely for learning purpose. I googled around but there are not enough examples for this combination.

> 11:17:31,272 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: Eclipselink_JPA   ...] 11:17:31,384 WARN 
>   [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000181: No appropriate connection
>   provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying
>   connections 11:17:31,405 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."HelloWeb.war#Eclipselink_JPA":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."HelloWeb.war#Eclipselink_JPA":
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   Eclipselink_JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>   [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1] Caused
>   by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   Eclipselink_JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection
>   cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set   at
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
>     ... 9 more
>
> 11:17:31,415 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "HelloWeb.war")]) - failure description:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"HelloWeb.war#Eclipselink_JPA\"" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit.\"HelloWeb.war#Eclipselink_JPA\":
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   Eclipselink_JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Eclipselink_JPA] Unable to build
>   EntityManagerFactory
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set"}}

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `Spring` + `EclipseLink` as the JPA provider, but logs show `Hibernate` exceptions. Are you "mixing" `EclipseLink` and `Hibernate`. Could you also post your `JPA`-related properties and `Spring` beans configuration?

Comment: I think Jboss + spring are trying to load Hibernate. In order to force my webApp to load eclipseLink I have a java class annotated with "@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories" and methods returning "getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" to force the webApp to use eclipselink. but somehow it sill uses hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by adding the following property in persistence.xml -
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

Now when I deploy my webApp on Jboss, it uses the eclipseLink JPA to load EntityManagerFactory instead of the default Hibernate.